# How to extend a class when one of the optional argument is not a member variable and it is required?

Tags: flutter, dart, subclass, extends

Here is the code. We have a `TabController` (from sdk), I am extending this `TabController` class:

```dart
class TabController extends ChangeNotifier {
   int length;
   TabController({ int initialIndex = 0,
      @required this.length, 
      @required TickerProvider vSync
   }):assert(length != null),
       assert(vSync != null);

} //end of TabController

class AppTabController extends TabController {

    AppTabController(int mInitialIndex,
       int mLength,
      TickerProvider mVsync):super(length: mLength, mVsync: vsync ){}

}
```

Now this `AppTabController`'s constructor is giving syntax error. Seems like I can't extend `TabController class` because:

1. `vsync` is not a member variable of `TabController`
2. There are some assertions in `TabController` constructor itself due to which if the required args are not passed then it will crash.

These are the compile errors:

1. error: The named parameter `vsync` isn't defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `this.length` requires member variable.
2. `@required` requires `assert`
3. use `:` instead of `=`
4. make a class extended `TickerProvider` because it is `abstract class`. I made `myTickerProvider` as the example.

```
AppTabController appTabController = new AppTabController(mLength:10, mVsync:new myTickerProvider());

class TabController extends ChangeNotifier {
  int length;
  TabController({
    int initialIndex = 0,
    @required this.length,
    @required TickerProvider vSync
  }) : assert(length != null),
       assert(vSync != null);
} //end of TabController

class AppTabController extends TabController {

  AppTabController({int mInitialIndex,
      int mLength,
      TickerProvider mVsync}):super(length: mLength, vSync: mVsync);
}


class myTickerProvider extends TickerProvider{
  @override
  Ticker createTicker(onTick) {
    // TODO: implement createTicker
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response but now it says vSync - is not defined

Comment: @RahulLohra How to create an instance of `AppTabController`. I have just part of your code.

Comment: Yes you are correct, on how to pass args to super constructor, but it looks like if any argument is not defined as member variable of the super class, we can't properly extend it due to assertions.

Comment: @RahulLohra Updated. But, I can't give you full code because I have no your full code. Just, I updated an example.

Comment: Sorry I think my statement is a bit confusing to you, I am trying to say 
`super(length: mLength, vSync: mVsync);` - this will give **syntax error** because `vSync` is not a member variable of `TabController`

Comment: @RahulLohra Please make sure whether you use `this.vSync` or `vSync`. From your question, It was just `vSync`. And, My code does not have any errors now in my android studio.

Answer (score 0):

**@RahulLohra**

If you use your own **`TickerProvider`** (as in the **@yahocho** example), you will need to implement the correct abstract method **`createTicker`**, as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class MyTickerProvider extends TickerProvider{
  @override
  Ticker createTicker(onTick) =>
      Ticker(onTick, debugLabel: kDebugMode ? 'created by $this' : null);
}
```

Notes:

- Name class using **UpperCamelCase**. (Please, see [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart) guidelines)
- If you **`return null`** in **`createTicker`**, you will see an error in the log every time you run the animation.